# How to work with NSInputStream in Iphone Sdk

Tags: objective-c

Can Any one suggest me which is the better approach to work with NSInputStream.
And I need a sample code to implement it in an sample application.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for a class often provides links to sample code. The [NSInputStream documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does this.

Comment: I didnt found any sample code in this document .if u found it please send me.